# How to disable theme caching in keycloak 20

Tags: keycloak

I am running keycloak 20.0.3 in docker with setting  KC_CACHE: ispn
I have  a few themes for the login page.  How can I disable and clear  theme caching ? Newer version of keycloak does not have standalone_ha.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you start keycloak in development mode theme caching should be deactivated automatically.

Call:

```
podman|docker run --name mykeycloak -p 8080:8080 \
    -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=change_me \
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest \
    start-dev
```

(from: https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers)

If it doesn't work add the following params to the startup script:

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --spi-theme-static-max-age=-1 --spi-theme-cache-themes=false --spi-theme-cache-templates=false
```

(from: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#creating-a-theme)

I start it from docker-compose like this:

```
    entrypoint: [ "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev",
      # deactivate theme caching during theme development
              "--spi-theme-static-max-age=-1",
              "--spi-theme-cache-themes=false",
              "--spi-theme-cache-templates=false"
      # ...
    ]
```

Comment: despite `--spi-theme-static-max-age=-1 --spi-theme-cache-themes=false --spi-theme-cache-templates=false` line is from the official docs, my designers complain it does not disables cache completely.

While the `start-dev` helped.